# comparing field from database with integer in php

Tags: php, sql, database, authentication

I pulled usernames and passwords from database, and they match, I can pass the login page. But I want to restrict some access to users, and provide access to admins, i do this with field `admin` in database. `admin` is int, and can have values 1 and 0. This code always enters `else` barnch of  this `if ($result == '1')`.

It is truly annoying, can you provide some clues?

```
$sql="SELECT admin FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";

$result=mysql_query($sql);


if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
     $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
     if ($result == '1'){
      echo "uspeh admine";
     }else{
      echo "uspeh korisnice";
     }

 }else{
    echo "neuspeh";
 }
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($result)` produce?

Comment: it returns this:
resource(3) of type (mysql result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$result` is a the resource for the results. You need to use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` or similar.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row['admin'] == '1') {
  echo "uspeh admine";
} else { 
  echo "uspeh korisnice";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get an array representation of the query's results:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

echo $row['some_key_maybe_id'];
```